# Finding global maxima while filtering the noise in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, regression

I am trying for quite long time to do the following in Python, for a new app that I am currently working on:

**Inputs:**

1. `list_of_points` - n sample points x. Each has d dimensions (each is represented as a list), where d is assumed to be large (the larger the better).
2. `list_of_values` - n values "hidden function" f. That is, `list_of_values[i] = f(list_of_points[i]) + noise`
3. `domain` - the d-minsional range on which f is defined, and thus `list_of_points` are also in this domain. The domain can possibly be the whole R^d.

**Output:** list of points that are global maxima of f on `domain`.

In order to filter the noise, I decided to use regression to estimate f, and only then to look for its maxima points.

Summarizing the above to a pseudo-code, we get:

```
def filter_noise_and_return_global_maxima(list_of_points, list_of_values, domain, degree_of_regression_polynomial):
    f = polynomial_regression(list_of_points, list_of_values, degree = degree_of_regression_polynomial)
    return f.global_maxima(domain)
```

Now I was trying to figure out how to do that, and I could not find any way to do it, especially if I want the code to run in a reasonable time (considering that the dimension d is rather big).

For the polynomial regression I found the following in the web:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model

X = [[0.44, 0.68], [0.99, 0.23]]
vector = [109.85, 155.72]
predict= [0.49, 0.18]

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
predict_ = poly.fit_transform(predict)

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_, vector)
print(clf.predict(predict_))
```

But unfortunately this raises errors. Also, I am not sure how to produce the polynomial for sympy that is used below.

Finally, for finding the global maxima I found this:

```
from sympy.calculus.util import *
x = symbols('x')
f = (x**3 / 3) - (2 * x**2) - 3 * x + 1

print(minimum(f, x, ivl))
print(maximum(f, x, ivl))
print(stationary_points(f, x, ivl))
```

But I am not sure if choosing a symbolic computatin is a good choise as I deal with a large dimension, and also I didn't realize how to use it for the multivariate case. For example, the folloing does not work `f = x[0]**2+ 2*x[1]`.

Comment: Do you have y or dependent variable on your datasets? Or you only have x or independent variables (train and test)? If you don't have y then you cannot fit.

Comment: Yes, sure. I edited my question to emphasize that

Comment: Can you give a single sample in the `list_of_points`?

Comment: ```list_of_points=[[1,2,3.2],[2,4.2, 5.1], [-1,0.1, 0.9]]
list_of_values=[4,5,6],
domain=[[-10,10], [-10,10], [-10, 10]]#-10<=x,y,z<=10, degree_of_regression_polynomial=1
```

Comment: `p1=[1,2,3.2], p2=[2,4.2, 5.1], p3=[-1,0.1, 0.9]` and their corresponding values are 4, 5 and 6 respectively. Was this correct? We will create a model that will fit these values. From the given p1 with dimension 3 plus its value we are now dealing with a 4D data is this right? What exactly is `Output: list of points that are global maxima of f on domain.` Do you mean that after building our model, we will search the point with a maximum value?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach of how to use linear regression with polynomial features which uses your pseudo code.

##### Code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


def minimize_mse():
    num_processor = 1
    X_train = [[0.44, 0.68], [0.99, 0.23]]
    X_test = [[0.24, 0.48], [0.29, 0.73]]

    print(f'X_train rows: {np.array(X_train).shape[0]}, X_train columns: {np.array(X_train).shape[1]}')

    y_train = [109.85, 155.72]
    y_test = [0.24, 0.58]

    best_mse = None
    best_degree = 1

    for d in range(1, 4):  # 1 to 3 degrees
        poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=d)

        # Increase the number of features or column based on degree to improve the fit.
        # Rows or number of datasets are not increased.
        X_train_p = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
        X_test_p = poly.fit_transform(X_test)

        clf = linear_model.LinearRegression(n_jobs=num_processor)  # our model
        clf.fit(X_train_p, y_train)

        y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_p)
        mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
        print(f'degree: {d}, ytest: {y_test}, ypred: {y_pred}, mse: {mse}')

        if best_mse is None or mse < best_mse:
            best_mse = mse
            best_degree = d

    print(f'best mse: {best_mse:0.2f}, best degree: {best_degree}')


# start
minimize_mse()
```

##### Output

```
X_train rows: 2, X_train columns: 2
degree: 1, ytest: [0.24, 0.58], ypred: [108.03336634 100.31267327], mse: 10783.007971615527
degree: 2, ytest: [0.24, 0.58], ypred: [109.1846578  102.28740262], mse: 11106.667105279808
degree: 3, ytest: [0.24, 0.58], ypred: [109.68924338 103.82600437], mse: 11319.43714729889
best mse: 10783.01, best degree: 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but I wanted is to make a polynomial regression to get some function f, and then to find f's maxima on some domain, for example on the d-dimensional unit sphere, could you show me how to do this? (this is, actually, where I had the most difficulties)

Comment: But you already wrote `input: n sample points of a function f` that means the f() is an input. Sorry, I think you need to describe the problem properly.

Comment: As you suggest, I edited my question, and simplified it to the main difficulty I face.